# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: $in needs an array

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo-3.x

I am getting error as pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: $in needs an array
while running the following code:-

```
rom pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.dbref import DBRef
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import sys
sys.path.append('/etc/insight')
import constants
constant = constants.Constants()
# Create MongoDB Connection
mongoconn = MongoClient(constant.MONGO_HOST, readPreference=constant.READ_PREFERENCE)
db = mongoconn[constant.MONGO_USERNAME]
# Mongo authentication to connect to database
auth = db.authenticate(constant.MONGO_USERNAME, constant.MONGO_PASSWORD)


# Query in network
nw = list(db.network.find({'orgId':{'$exists':True}},{'_id':1}))

print(nw)

# Query in networkSetting
networkIds = []

for id in nw:
    output = list(db.networkSetting.find({'networkId':{'$in':id['_id']},'locationRegion.wirelessCountryRegion':'JP'},{'networkId':1}))
    networkIds.append(output)



print(networkIds)
```

Can anyone please help me why I am getting this error.
I have tried writing:-

```
output = list(db.networkSetting.find({'networkId':{'$in':list(id['_id'])},'locationRegion.wirelessCountryRegion':'JP'},{'networkId':1}))
```

But then it is saying that ObjectId is not iterable.
Can anyone solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$in` requires an array, but your filter only needs a simple string search, so your query should be:

```
output = list(db.networkSetting.find({'networkId': id['_id'], 'locationRegion.wirelessCountryRegion': 'JP'}, {'networkId': 1}))
```